# Finding the position of a well-defined triangle based on distances between each corner and a point with known coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have

- a triangle $ABC$ with known side lengths $a = \overline{BC}, b = \overline{AC}, c = \overline{AB}$,
- three points $D, E, F$ with known coordinates and
- the known distances $d = \overline{AD}, e = \overline{EB}, f = \overline{FC}$

in two-dimensional space. How do I find the coordinates of points $A, B$ and $C$?

Intuitively I think if given values allow for a solution it should be unique, since the triangle could move around in two-dimensional space in exactly three ways (translation along x and y and rotation) and each of the three corners is constrained by distance to one of the three other points.

I have tried creating a linear system of six equations from the definitions of $a, b, c, d, e, f$ but have been unable to solve it or come up with a different approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Context: The actual problem is in three-dimensional space with a hexagon (six points: three for translation along each axis and three for rotation) instead of a triangle that I tried to simplify into this.

**Edit**: Thank you Jean Marie for what you pointed out. We can assume triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ aren't congruent.

Comment: To clarify before I attempt an answer: do we need to determine the exact coordinates of A,B,C, or does it suffice to construct a triangle congruent to ABC (that is, one whose side lengths are as required, but not necessarily in the same location and orientation in the coordinate plane)?

Comment: @JivanPal The goal is to find the coordinates of points at the required distance to D, E, F that form a triangle that is congruent to A, B, C.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised it there were at least two solutions in general. See the Wikipedia article [Linkage (mechanical)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(mechanical)) with the animation of a 4 bar linkage at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:4_bar_linkage_animated.gif – if you replace $A,B,C,D,E$ on the drawing with your $E,D,A,B,C$ symbols, then you can place your $F$ point somewhere close to the purple curve and see the upper vertex of the triangle can touch or cross the circle around $F$ with radius $f$ possibly from one to four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with complex numbers, and assimilating a point with its associated complex number, we can write :

$$A=D+d \exp(i\theta_D), \ \ B=E+e \exp(i \theta_E), \ \ C=F+f \exp(i \theta_F)\tag{1}$$

for certain angles, giving the 3 constraints :

$$\begin{cases}|E-D+e \exp(i \theta_E)-\exp(i\theta_D)|&=&c\\|F-E+e \exp(i \theta_F)-\exp(i\theta_E)|&=&a\\ |D-F+e \exp(i \theta_D)-\exp(i\theta_F)|&=&b\end{cases}\tag{2}
$$

If you want an approximate solution, you can use brute force : divide for example each circle into 360°, and consider the $360^3$ possibilities for $(\theta_E,\theta_F,\theta_G)$ (three embedded "for" loops) and test for each possibility whether the LHS of the 3 equations is close or not to its RHS (of course, this must be turned into a more effective formulation with a certain threshold, etc...). Hopefully, one of the combinations (sometimes more) will be in agreement with a at most one degree tolerance.

If you want arbitrary precision, you must turn to iterative methods (multidimensional Newton). If this case,  one should work on a system of 3 real equations with 3 unknowns that are obtained by squaring all constraints in (3),

No hope (IMHO) that there is an explicit solution.

---

Remark : a particular case : there is at least a case where the conditions given provide an infinite number of solutions : it is when ABC and DEF have identical lengthes and distances $d=e=f$ (see diagram below) :

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Triangle DEF in black. An infinite number of positions of triangle ABC are possible.*

Another case where there are (at least) 2 solutions

$D(2,0), E(6,4), F(5,1)$ with $AB=4\sqrt{2}, AC=BC=4, d=e=2, f=\sqrt{2}$

You can have $A(0,0),B(4,4),C(4,0)$ or $A(2,2),B(6,6),C(6,2).$

Comment: Thank you. Edited the question to account for this.

Comment: But even if the triangles are not congruent, you can have no unicity (see my other example...). It is true that again it is rather specific examples : I agree that in the general case, it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: The so-called "Cayley-Menger determinant" could be a tool... in the general case.

Comment: As far as I understood the Cayley-Menger determinant couldn't help with the original problem in three-dimensional space I described though. I am looking for a general solution that can be used on the original problem.

Comment: I have written a first part which proposes a method.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted the answer since it is a solution to my question. However it sadly doesn't really help with the original problem since doing the same with six points would make it way too complex computationally.

Comment: A remark : My brute force solution isn't good. One can reduce in a drastic way the choices : being given $\theta_D$ (which amounts to place point $A$), determine the intersections of circle with center $D$ and radius $c$ : with circle with center E and radius $D$ : there are $0,1$ or $2$ points, i.e., candidates for being $B$. If such $B$ exist, use another idea : as you know the lengths of triangle $ ABC$, you know as well its angles... Therefore, knowing $A$ and $B$, you have a unique $C$ (unique if you take orentation into account). It remains to test whether distance $FC$ is close to $f$.